# How to retrieve position of selected node in another node-set

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

```
<Form>
<Table>
<Row>
<Column></Column>
<Column></Column>
<Column></Column>
</Row>
<Row>
<Column id="xxx"></Column>
<Column></Column>
<Column></Column>
</Row>
<Row>
<Column></Column>
<Column></Column>
<Column></Column>
</Row>
</Table>
</Form>
```

How to select position of row that contains column with id "xxx" in context of all rows in Table?

Comment: From which context are doing this - and for what purpose?

Comment: @michael.hor257k for example <xsl:template match="Column">

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. Why would you need to know the position of a specific column from the context of every column?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have to estimate if rowspan of column which is above current column covers current column right sibling. Generally problem is about rowspans and colspans in head-like rows inside big tables in xml->html transformation. I simplify this problem as much as i could.

Comment: Well, it's not getting any clearer - so why don't we leave it at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: *How to select position of row that contains column with id "xxx" in context of all rows in Table?*

Try:

```
 "count(Row[Column/@id = 'xxx']/preceding-sibling::Row) + 1"
```